# In XML Schema, any way to prevent a global element from overriding a local one?

Tags: xml, types, nested, schema

When we define a W3C XML Schemas with types and local elements and have only one global element defined to serve as the root, it appears that the name of that global element can not be re-used inside the other elements, it will always be assumed to be of the type of the global element, not of the declared type for the nested element.

Consider this example:

```
<document xmlns="myns">
  <id>123</id>
  <content>
    <document>
      <text>Lorem Ipsum ...</text>
    </document>
  </content>
</document>
```

There are two elements named "document" they are supposed to have different types, the root element type RootDocument and the nested document type NestedDocument. The following Schema would say that:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="myns" targetNamespace="myns" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="document" type="RootDocument"/>

  <xs:complexType name="RootDocument">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="content" type="Content"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Content">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="document" type="NestedDocument"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="NestedDocument">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But the problem is, the nested element named "document" inside the "content" element will be validated using the type Document1 of the global element named "document" even though per schema it is defined of type Document2 at that point.

Is there anything one can do to override the global element definition by the local element definition?

Note: using a different namespace for the nested document element is not an option here.

Edited based on response by Michael Kay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your schema. Firstly, the three references to type="string" should be type="xs:string". Secondly, your schema requires the local document element to have an "id" child, which is not present in your instance. On fixing these errors, your instance validates against your schema.

Local element declarations work how you want them to, and I don't know where you got the idea that they don't.

Comment: Thank you Michael, you are right. I corrected the errors you pointed out. Strange, I had a more complex example where this seemed to be exactly the problem, but now reproduced in the small example it seems all good.

Comment: I have verified it again, it works just fine. The reason why it didn't work as expected for me was that the "content" tag was not recognized and _that_ was why it used the global "document" element instead of the local element I expected.